# How to scale a SwiftUI Image including its overlay?

Tags: swift, image, swiftui, position, scale

Given this view with an image that has an overlay:

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image("image")
            .overlay {
                Image("logo")
                    .position(x: 20, y: 130) // I want to freely position the overlay image
            }
    }
}
```

The size of the images shouldn’t matter. I my example they are 150×150 pixels (“image”) and 20×20 pixels (logo).

[image]

How can I scale this up to its bounds (like superviews frame), **including** the overlay?

### Some must-have conditions:

- I need to **freely position** the overlay image, so I can not use the `alignment` parameter of `overlay` in conjunction with a padding on the logo.
- I also need to **position** the overlay image **absolutely**, not relatively. So I can’t use a `GeometryReader` (or `alignment`).
- I need the view to be **reusable** in different scenarios (different devices, different view hierarchies). That means I **don’t know the scale factor**, so I can’t use `scaleEffect`.

### I tried:

#### A) `.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)`

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image("image")
            .resizable()
            .overlay {
                Image("logo")
                    .position(x: 20, y: 130)
            }
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
    }
}
```

#### B) `.scaledToFit()`

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image("image")
            .resizable()
            .overlay {
                Image("logo")
                    .position(x: 20, y: 130)
            }
            .scaledToFit()
    }
}
```

#### C) Making logo resizable

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image("image")
            .resizable()
            .overlay {
                Image("logo")
                    .resizable()
                    .position(x: 20, y: 130)
            }
            .scaledToFit() // or .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        }
}
```

A and B looking like this:
[image]

C looking like this:
[image]

Both of which gave me a relative position of the logo that was different from the original (see linked screenshot). The relative size differs as well (it is now too small).

Wrapping in a stack and scale this stack instead also didn’t help.

### [UPDATE] Accepted answer

Apparently not having a real view hierarchy in SwiftUI vs UIKit comes at a price. Scaling a hierarchy shouldn’t be that complicated imho. Instead I still would expect `.scaledToFit` (if added at the end) to scale everything before it (see A), B), and C)).

Adapted [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71091160/18187713) (minus `contentSize` and `alignment: .topLeading`):

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image("image")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .overlay {
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    let imageSize = CGSize(width: 150, height: 150)
                    let logoSize = CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)
                    let logoPosition = CGPoint(x: 20, y: 130)
                    Image("logo")
                        .resizable()
                        .position(
                            x: logoPosition.x / imageSize.width * geometry.size.width,
                            y: logoPosition.y / imageSize.height * geometry.size.height
                        )
                        .frame(
                            width: logoSize.width / imageSize.width * geometry.size.width,
                            height: logoSize.height / imageSize.height * geometry.size.height
                        )
                }
            }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: so do you want logo position at the bottom left side ?

Comment: I want to freely position the image in the overlay. The "dog and logo" is just an example for the general problem: resizing an image with all its content.

Comment: try to put .resizable() to image logo also.

Comment: Making logo resizable did not work: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jB8CY.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then like this with GeometryReader:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let imageSize = CGSize(width: 150, height: 150) // Size of orig. image
    let logoPos = CGSize(width: 10, height: 120) // Position of Logo in relation to orig. image
    let logoSize = CGSize(width: 20, height: 20) // Size of logo in relation to orig. image
    
    @State private var contentSize = CGSize.zero
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Image("dog")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
        
            .overlay(
                GeometryReader { geo in
                    Color.clear.onAppear {
                        contentSize = geo.size
                    }
                }
            )
            .overlay(
                Image(systemName: "circle.hexagongrid.circle.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .foregroundColor(.pink)
                    .offset(x: logoPos.width / imageSize.width * contentSize.width,
                            y: logoPos.height / imageSize.height * contentSize.height)
                    .frame(width: logoSize.width / imageSize.width * contentSize.width,
                           height: logoSize.height / imageSize.height * contentSize.height)
                , alignment: .topLeading)
    }
}
```

Comment: Not bad. Don’t see the need to store `contentSize` though. Also: In case the size of the logo asset changes, I would like to retrieve the size dynamically, not hardcoded (`imageSize` and `logoSize). How would I get the size of an `Image`? (other than using UIKit; `UIImage(named: "image")?.size`)

Comment: `contentSize`is necessary to hand the size value over from the `GeometryReader` to the logo overlay. SwiftUI doesn't give you the size of the underlying image, you will have to go with UIKit. – But if the logo asstes change, then your absolute position won't work anymore either, so you can go back to #2 in my first answer :)

Comment: True, true. Was hoping there is a less verbose solution. Apparently not having a real view hierarchy in SwiftUI vs UIKit comes at a price. Scaling a hierarchy shouldn’t be that complicated imho. For me it works withouth `contentSize` (and `alignment`). I updated my question with your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the absolute positioning of the logo. I see two ways:

1. scale the whole resulting image with .scaleEffect.
   Be aware this is a render scaling of the underlying image, it will not be redrawn in the new size, so can become blurry.

   ```
    Image("dog")
        .overlay {
            Image(systemName: "circle.hexagongrid.circle.fill")
                .foregroundColor(.pink)
                .position(x: 20, y: 130)
        }        
        .scaleEffect(2.0)
   ```

or – and my preference
2. Position the Logo relative to the lower left corner

```
    ZStack(alignment: .bottomLeading) {
        Image("dog")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
        Image(systemName: "circle.hexagongrid.circle.fill")
            .resizable()
            .foregroundColor(.pink)
            .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
            .padding()
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Can’t use (1): I need the view to be reusable in different scenarios. So I don’t know the scale factor. I also can not use (2): I need to position the overlay image absolutely, not relatively. Thank you a lot anyways!

Comment: are your original images all the same size?

Comment: `image` and `logo` in my example are of different size (150 and 20 pixel squared)